# How much time does it have to pass

Tags: syntax

Is 1 wrong? If so, why is it wrong? I think 2 is correct.

1 How much time does it have to pass before... something happens.

2 How much time has to pass before... something happens.

Comment: Sorry, I meant "How much time has to pass"

Comment: Why is 1 wrong?

Comment: (1) is wrong because time passes, 'it' doesn't pass time - although a person can 'pass their time in' doing some activity.

Comment: 1 is wrong because it sounds like there's something, "it", and that thing has to "pass some time", whatever that means.